# Failed to syncronize cache for repo 'fedora' ... (possible proxy issues)

Tags: fedora, sudo, proxy, cache, dnf

I just started on a [fedora build](https://getfedora.org/). Just managed to add myself to the sudoers file, so now I am attempting to grab vim. I do a

```
sudo dnf install vim
```

and get hit with the following error message.

```
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora' from 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-23&arch=x86_64': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-23&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]
```

To me, this looks like a proxy issue. I attempt this

```
export http_proxy="<my proxy>"
```

And then retry

```
sudo dnf install vim
```

Same response. I know the proxy is correct, as it worked for me on a previous RedHat build, so can someone recomend me the next steps to try here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I found that I needed to open

```
/etc/dnf/dnf.conf
```

and add the line

```
proxy=http://<my_proxy>:<port>
```

Simply setting the http_proxy in the bash shell was not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem by adding the proxy entry to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`.  However we use the default http port 80 so I set the proxy as follows:

```
proxy=http://192.168.0.1
```

This did not work.  The proxy setting required the port.

```
proxy=http://192.168.0.1:80
```